# ActiveRecord next item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently getting back a list of items in a prioritized order:

```
@priotizedorder = @categories.order(:priority)
```

What I want to create is a button that allows a user to get to the next category from an item. I'm trying to do that by saying:

```
@activecategory = @categories.where(:name => params[:cat]).first

@nextcategory = @priotizedorder.select {|item|'name' == @activecategory}
```

But that's returning an empty array:

> []

**How do I select the next category in an active record?**

Comment: As you accepted my answer, upvote it if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your question is not clear to me, you are asking for next category but you are searching the given category in the order, according to my knowledge I am providing the solution

1. Your statement must be

   ```
    @nextcategory = @priotizedorder.select {|item| item == @activecategory}
   ```

   When you are using 'select', above statement returns an array of results matching with the value, you should take the first value from the array.

   ```
    i.e., @nextcategory = @priotizedorder.select {|item| item == @activecategory}.first
   ```

   (OR) You can use find method

   ```
    @nextcategory = @priotizedorder.find {|item| item == @activecategory}
   ```
2. If you want to select the next prioritised category of given item, then use the below code

   ```
    @currentcategory = @priotizedorder.find {|item| item == @activecategory}
    @currentcategory_index = @priotizedorder.index(@currentcategory)
    @nextcategory = @priotizedorder[@currentcategory_index+1]
   ```